# Zend ACL and access to specific objects

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-acl

I need an ACL for my application layer and I've been looking into Zend ACL which seems to cover my needs but I'm confused by the following [1]:

> For example, if a default rule is to be applied to each building in a
>   city, one would simply assign the rule to the city, instead of
>   assigning the same rule to each building. Some buildings may require
>   exceptions to such a rule, however, and this can be achieved in
>   `Zend\Permissions\Acl\Acl` by assigning such exception rules to each
>   building that requires such an exception.

This is great. Exactly what I need. However, how do I accomplish this?

From reading through the documentation for Zend ACL, I can't actually find an example of this. So, lets say I have a `City` and `Building` resource and each implements the `ResourceInterface`. Something like this:

```
class City implements ResourceInterface {

   public function getResourceId()
   {
      return "city"; // Is this supposed to be the "type" or the "unique Id"?
   }

   public $buildings = array();

}

class Building implements ResourceInterface {

   public function getResourceId()
   {
      return "building"; // Again, the "type" or "unique Id"?
   }

}
```

As the comments in the code above might already make clear, what is the resource Id? does it represent the "type" of the resource, i.e. this is a City or Building, or does it require to be a unique Id, i.e. "city-1", etc?

If the answer is that it needs to be the "type" then the question becomes; how do I specify unique buildings? However, if the answer is that the Id needs to be unique then the question becomes; how do I identify the "type" of the resource and "blanket" permission each building as stated in the quote taken from the documentation.

Any insight would be much appreciated.

[1] http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.permissions.acl.intro.html

Comment: maybe it can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11668785/zend-acl-dynamic-assertion it has an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `resource Id` needs to be a unique value. and for assigning global rules you need to use inheritance for the resources . simple you need to pass the `city` resource as the parent for the `building` resource when you adding resources to the acl.

here is a sample :

```
$acl = new Acl();

//the original Acl resource class takes a `resourceId` as constructor parameter
$mycity1 = new Resource('mycity1');
$acl->addResource($mycity1);

$mybuiding1 = new Resource('mybulding1');
//city is the buildings parent
$acl->addResource($mybuiding1,$mycity1);

//you dont even have to create a class just define the resource as string
$acl->addResource('secure_buildings',$mycity1);

$acl->addRole('myrole1');
//roles have inheritance too
$acl->addRole('myrole2','myrole1');

//myrole1 and myrole2 has access to city and all its building
$acl->allow('myrole1','mycity1');
//myrole2 has access to city and all its building except 'secure_buildings'
$acl->deny('myrole2','secure_buildings');
```

the child resource `bulding` inherits the rules from parent `city` if none is defined for it.

UPDATE for comment :

ACL doesn't know and doesn't care what resource type you have as long as they have unique resource ids, acl threats all resources as equal and only looks for `resourceId` and inheritance.

when you defining the rules you only need to provide the `resourceId` for the `allow` and `deny` , it doesn't matter what type they are as long as they are defined as a resource and added to the ACL's stack.

and when you doing `$acl->inAllowed` you only need a `roleId` and `resourceId` and again acl doesn't care about their type , only that they have been defined as a resource abd that they have parent or not...

Sample : i hope this is enough sample

```
$acl = new Acl();
$acl->addResource('City'); //all the cities
$acl->addResource('myCity1', 'City'); //city1 inherits City
$acl->addResource('Building', 'City'); //all the buildings in all the cities
$acl->addResource('normal_buildings', 'Building');
$acl->addResource('secure_buildings', 'Building');
$acl->addResource('top_secure_buildings', 'secure_buildings');

$acl->addRole('Civilian');
$acl->addRole('High_Level_Security', 'Civilian');

$acl->allow('Civilian', 'City');
$acl->deny('Civilian', 'secure_buildings');

$acl->allow('High_Level_Security', 'secure_buildings');
$acl->deny('High_Level_Security', 'top_secure_buildings');

var_dump($acl->isAllowed('Civilian', 'City'));//true  -> direct allow rule
var_dump($acl->isAllowed('Civilian', 'myCity1'));//true  -> inherited from City allow rule
var_dump($acl->isAllowed('Civilian', 'Building'));//true  -> inherited from City allow rule
var_dump($acl->isAllowed('Civilian', 'normal_buildings'));//true  -> inherited from City allow rule
var_dump($acl->isAllowed('Civilian', 'secure_buildings'));//false  -> direct deny rule
var_dump($acl->isAllowed('Civilian', 'top_secure_buildings'));//false   -> inherited from secure_building deny rule

var_dump($acl->isAllowed('High_Level_Security', 'City'));//true  -> inherited from Civilian->City allow rule
var_dump($acl->isAllowed('High_Level_Security', 'myCity1'));//true  -> inherited from Civilian->City allow rule
var_dump($acl->isAllowed('High_Level_Security', 'Building'));//true  -> inherited from Civilian->City allow rule
var_dump($acl->isAllowed('High_Level_Security', 'normal_buildings'));//true  -> inherited from Civilian->City allow rule
var_dump($acl->isAllowed('High_Level_Security', 'secure_buildings'));//true  -> direct allow rule
var_dump($acl->isAllowed('High_Level_Security', 'top_secure_buildings'));//false  -> direct deny rule
```

Comment: updated the answer with sample, and you realize that Zend in open source and you can actually check then source code to understand whats happening ? right ? if you check the code you will see that acl doesn't give **** what type the resource is, and if the resource has no direct rule it checks the parent and so on ...

Comment: Your last update makes total sense now. Thanks for your help.